# Java need help checking if string is instance

Tags: java, instance

I have an interface, GenericExpression, that gets extended to create expressions (ie AndExpression, OrExpression etc.).

Each GenericExpression implementation has a string that represents it (ie "&", "+", etc.) (stored as a static variable "stringRep")

Is there any way to take a user input String and check if it represents a GenericExpression?

If not (seems likely this is the case), is there any way to achieve a similar effect with a refactored design?

Thanks!

EDIT: Offered a little bit more detail above.

Also, the end goal is to be able to arbitrarily implement GenericExpression and still check if a string represents an instance of one of its subclasses. As such, I can't just store a map of implementation - string representation pairs, because it would make make it so GenericExpression is no longer easily extendible.

Also, this is homework

Comment: This looks like homework. If it is homework, please tag it as such. Also, you'll need to provide more information, possibly a lot more. To start with, what do you mean by "Each GenericExpression implementation has a string that represents it (ie "&", "+", etc.)." ? If you simply mean that the GenericExpression is *prefixed* by that string, then all you need is a method that tests whether the input String's prefix matches against one of these prefixes. The String class provides you with methods that can help you with this checking.

Comment: You could write a regular expression to test this - allow each instance of GenericExpression to register "their part" of the regex in a table somewhere perhaps?

Comment: @Dan it is for homework, my apologies for not marking it as such. Also I'll edit the question to provide more detail.

Comment: @awoodland The table idea is a good one, but I'm not sure where to store it. My reedited question should help clarify

Answer (score 3):

Well I think you will need to define somewhere what expressions are supported by your program. I think the best way is to use a [map](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), where you map your interface to strings. That way you can easily look up an expression with its representing string. Where you will define this map is dependant on your design. One possibility is a static method in a helper class that resolves expressions to a string like:

```
Expressions.get("&").invoke(true, false);
```

Where `get` is a static method on `Expressions` that looks up the desired expression in a static map. You will have to initialize this map in a static initializer, or let the expression instances add themselves on creation.

**EDIT:**
 (I wanted to comment this on an answer but it seems to be deleted)
Personally I don't like the idea of classes registering themselves. It gives me the feeling of not being in control of my code. I would prefer to instantiate the classes in the `Expressions` class itself. The code for registering a class must be written for every new subclass anyway. I prefer to centralize this code in a single class so if I want to change logic or refactor, I only have to touch one class.

Comment: Thanks but I'm afraid I don't understand your edit? How would one instantiate the classes in the Expressions class?

Comment: Fill up the map in a static initializer. Instantiate all subclasses of your interface and add them to the map.